# Нечаянно поставил [301, L] permanent ссылку на домен сайта теперь сайт не работает, что делать?

Tags: .htaccess

домен сайта  делает редирект с `https:\\example.com`  к `https:\\example.com\wrong-url`

удалил htaccess rule но не помогает 
Что делать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер может кэшировать [код ответа](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) 301. Попробуйте очистить кэш.

Как это сделать в [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)/[Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Kак это сделать ?

Comment: В Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache
В Chrome: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Да  я думал какой то кеш  хостинга, 
не подумал что проблема в браузере спасибо.